# Asynchronous Database Access Layer in PureMVC

Tags: sqlite, actionscript-3, model-view-controller, data-access-layer, puremvc

I'm trying to refactor an existing project into PureMVC. This is an Adobe AIR desktop app taking advantage of the SQLite library included with AIR and building upon it with a few other libraries:

- Paul Robertson's excellent async [SQLRunner](http://probertson.com/projects/air-sqlite/)
- [promise-as3](https://github.com/CodeCatalyst/promise-as3) implementation of asynchronous promises
- [websql-js](http://websql-js.googlecode.com/hg/docs/websql.html) documentation for good measure

I made my current implementation of the database similar to websql-js's promise based SQL access layer and it works pretty well, however I am struggling to see how it can work in PureMVC.

Currently, I have my VOs that will be paired with DAOs (data access objects) for database access. Where I'm stuck is how to track the dbFile and sqlRunner instances across the entire program. The DAOs will need to know about the sqlRunner, or at the very least, the dbFile. Should the sqlRunner be treated as singleton-esque? Or created for every database query?

Finally, how do I expose the dbFile or sqlRunner to the DAOs? In my head right now I see keeping these in a DatabaseProxy that would be exposed to other proxies, and instantiate DAOs when needed. What about a DAO factory pattern?

I'm very new to PureMVC but I really like the structure and separation of roles. Please don't hesitate to tell me if this implementation simply will not work.

Comment: Apparently I need more reputation to post 3 or more links, but here is the link to websql-js documentation for good measure http://websql-js.googlecode.com/hg/docs/websql.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically in PureMVC you would use a `Proxy` to fetch remote data and populate the `VO`s used by your `View`, so in that respect your proposed architecture sounds fine.

`DAO`s are not a pattern I've ever seen used in conjunction with PureMVC (which is not to say that nobody does or should). However, if I was setting out to write a crud application in PureMVC, I would probably think in terms of a `Proxy` (or proxies) to read information from the database, and `Commands` to write it back.